# Why is it an adverbial clause?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, clauses

> "We did not make reservations on time, **so we will not go to the representation**."

I think this is a compound sentence consisting of two co-ordinate independent clauses, joined by the co-ordinating conjunction "so".

But I found on the internet that **"so we will not go to the representation"** is an adverbial clause.

How is it possible?

Edit : **Consecutive adverbial clause** : *In these clauses the conclusion or logical continuation of what has been said in the main sentence is stated : (1) Peter usually fantasizes a lot **so you do not believe his stories**. (2) We did not make reservations on time, **so we will not go to the representation**.*  [SOURCE : **Wikipedia**]. But, practically, the two clauses appear to be co-ordinate independent clauses. Hence, the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. This is tricky.

You are correct that this is a compound sentence and *so* is a coordinating conjunction in this sentence.

I'm not sure where you found this other information, but let me try to explain how this is confusing. *So* is a coordinating conjunction here, but in other situations—-specifically, when it is used to mean *so that*-—it can be a [subordinating conjunction](https://ginsengenglish.com/blog/parts-of-speech-in-english), and in this case it would be providing adverbial information.

Consider this example:
*We ate a late breakfast so we wouldn't be hungry on the train.*

Read this carefully and note that so has a different meaning in this example than it does in your sentence. Here it is a subordinating conjunction. A good way to confirm this is by switching the order of the clauses:

*So we wouldn't be hungry on the train, we ate a late breakfast.*

You can move a subordinate clause to the front of a sentence, but you cannot do this with a coordinating conjunction (your example does not have this flexibility).

In this example, the subordinate clause provides adverbial information. Thus it is an adverbial clause. It answers the question *why*.

Comment: The clause under discussion is : "so we will not go to the representation," How does it answer the question 'why'?

Comment: It's the last example sentence where it answers "why".

Comment: In the clause from your example, _so_ does **nor** answer the question _Why?_ Your understanding of your example was correct, as I said. As @JackO'Flaherty pointed out, I am introducing a second sentence to contrast with yours, showing another way that _so_ can be used as a conjunction. This other use of so is the source of the confusion.

Comment: As per Wikipedia, "so we will not go to the representation" is a consecutive adverbial clause.

Comment: Not really sure what to tell you except that I'm pretty certain that is an error. Wikipedia is useful, but for grammar, it often contains errors. Anyone can edit those pages, and it can be difficult to identify a truly authoritative source on issues like this. If you want a reputable and exhaustive source on adverbial clauses check out https://folk.uio.no/kjelljs/060AdverbialClauses.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As Rob's answer pointed out, "so" is a coordinating conjunction in the original post. Grammatically, it can be replaced by "and". It corresponds to this definition:
[American Heritage Dictionary "so" conj.(2)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=so)

> 2. With the result or consequence that: *He failed to appear, so we went on without him*.

"So" can also be a subordinating conjunction. See
[Grammarly "coordinating conjunctions"](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/coordinating-conjunctions/)
"... so can be used as both a coordinating conjunction and a subordinating conjunction. As a coordinating conjunction, so can link two independent clauses in a manner similar to **therefore**, and as a subordinating conjunction, it can link two unequal clauses (one independent clause and one dependent clause) in the sense of **so that**."

**So**, in this case of the quote in the OP, the clause is not adverbial.

Comment: The example I have posted is from Wikipedia. The source says that it's a 'consecutive adverbial clause. In these clauses the conclusion or logical continuation of what has been said in the main sentence is stated. (1) Peter usually fantasizes a lot [so you do not believe his stories]. (2) We did not make reservations on time, [so we will not go to the representation]. The bracketed parts are consecutive adverbial clause. But, practically, the two clauses appear to be co-ordinate independent clauses. Hence, the confusion.

Comment: isn't it a consecutive adverbial clause?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause